# Ubuntu 15.04 - Audio switches to Headphones after suspend, but there is no sound through headphones or speakers

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa, 15.04

Ok, so I have been getting a strange issue since I updated to 15.04. After a reboot, audio works fine through the speakers, and I'm able to plug the headphones in and it switches to them and works fine as well. This is the expected behaviour, only notable because on 14.10, plugging in headphones would not silence the speakers. However, after suspending and resuming, but not after every suspend/resume, audio will stop working. If I open the Sound Settings, it says it's playing through the headphones, but the headphones aren't plugged in. No audio plays through the speakers. Oddly, even if I plug in headphones, I get no sound. So far, I have tried force-reloading alsa when this happens, and I have tried a full purge/reinstall of alsa-base and pulseaudio, to no avail. Rebooting apparently fixes the problem until it happens again. Running aplay -l both when sound is working and when it isn't gives the following output (there is no change between the two states):

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

If anyone is able to help, that would be appreciated. If you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: Did you find a solution?